# MotionPlanning in Moveit only partly works?

Tags: ros, motion-planning, rviz, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
Hello List,
```

Using Indigo I created a setup with moveit setup assistent and an urdf for our crustcrawler arm.
The urdf is adapted from the smart_arm_robot.xacro from ua-ros-pkg.
The urdf works fine using rviz and joint_state_publisher.

But with Planning Request in Moveit/Rviz the eef-joint (wrist_roll_joint) gets DETACHED from the rest of the arm.
Normally the rest of the arm should follow, but it does NOT move while the (moved) eff-joint immediatly turns red.

The moveit-command however DOES work. I can see the moves in Rviz when I give e.g. "go rand".
Also the pr2 example does work perfectly.
You can find my setup in http://fwn06.housing.rug.nl/ros

I only used the setup wizard and used an urdf I am fairly confidant about.
Why does the planning in MotionPlanning not work ?

Thanks in advance,
Sietse

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206248/motionplanning-in-moveit-only-partly-works?/) by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) on ROS Answers with karma: 168 on 2015-03-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To answer my own question:
I had to flag "Allow Approximate IK Solutions" to get it to work.

I don't know why this is needed (of how I could have known this), but for the moment it works for me.

---

Originally posted by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) with karma: 168 on 2015-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-04-01**:
That option is almost always needed to work around the fact that your manipulator has < 6dofs, and the MoveIt interactive markers control a 6D Pose. The IK plugin used (probably KDL) cannot solve for a 6D pose with less than 6dof in your robot, hence the need to allow *approximate* solutions.

**Comment by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) on 2015-04-01**:
OK, clear. Thanks!